# Use odt2txt for Diff on Gitweb

Tags: git, gitweb, odt

I followed the instructions [here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitTips#How_to_use_git_to_track_OpenDocument_.28OpenOffice.2C_Koffice.29_files.3F) and I cannot get them to work.  I am using Git and Gitweb 1.7.5 on shared hosting, custom compiled and deployed using GNU Stow but basically following [this howto on Dreamhost](https://github.com/alharaka/private-git-on-dreamhost) (just forked, no modifications made to reflect Stow and other stuff).  Essentially I modfied my `~/.gitconfig` and `/path/to/repo/.gitattributes` and/or `/path/to/repo/info/attributes`; neither worked.  I still see this in the gitweb interface.

> diff --git a/2011/randomdoc.odt
>   b/2011/randomdoc.odt
>
> index 5890ee7..168582b 100644 (file)
>
> Binary files a/2011/randomdoc.odt and b/2011/randomdoc.odt differ

What am I doing wrong?  It does not even show

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem but after a torough search found the solution in a mail list: http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg160731.html

Modified config like this

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
[diff "odf"]
    textconv=odt2txt
```

Modified info/attributes:

```
*.ods diff=odf
*.odt diff=odf
*.odp diff=odf
```

Modified /etc/gitweb.conf:
    push @diff_opts, '--textconv';

**IMPORTANT**: As I've read, enabling diff_opts might lead to security problems allowing git users to execute code!

I've realized that is you the one writting on the list, anyway, I'll leave this here for future searches... :)

Answer (score 0):

gitweb might

- not honour these attributes, or
- your executables might not be reachable from within the webserver context

  - try specifying absolute paths to `git-oodiff`

Inside git-oodiff you can easily extend the environment for any other applications you need:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/ooutils:$PATH" # e.g.
```

Comment: `git-oodiff` exists for pre-1.6.4 versions of Git. Post-1.6.4 you use textconv to use custom commands to get text output for the diff.  [the method you mention is obsolete now, sort of](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitTips). I am perplexed because it appears it can access Git (which is not the normal one on the server, I compiled it and control it with Stow so I will have access to multiple versions).  The symlinks to `git` and `odt2txt` are in the same path, so one should work so long as the other does. Kind of at a loss.  I guess I have to ask the git mailing list.